# Add Link Column to DataTable After Ajax Call MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

On my view page I have a table (from a partial view) and a form.  I am using ajax to submit the form to my webapi controller.

On success I would like to add what was entered in the textbox to the first column, and links to Edit and Delete in the second column of a new row.

As of right now I am only working on the Edit link.

Here is my partial view table:

```
<table id="Table" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-6">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-6">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Admin)
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-6">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Here is my form jquery.ajax:

```
var table = $("#Table").DataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1] },
        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [1] }
    ]
});

$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: infoGetUrl,
        method: "post",
        data: $("form").serialize()
    }).success(function (data) {
        var editLink = document.createElement('a');
        editLink.href = "/controllerName/Edit/" + data.id;
        editLink.text = "Edit";

        table.row.add([
            $("#Textbox").val(),
            editLink
        ]).draw();
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error");
    });
});
```

The problem is that when this renders I get this:

[image]

It is not clickable and renders like this:

```
<tr class="even" role="row">
    <td class="sorting_1">John.Doe</td>
    <td>http://localhost:61888/controllerName/Edit/15</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, it is not rendered in an `a` tag, and I don't need the `http://localhost:61888` part of the link.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: try creating link as `var link = <a href='/controllerName/Edit/' + data.id>EDIT</a>`

Comment: @shantaram_t that worked. thank you. post as answer and I will accept

Comment: glad to hear that it helped ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating link as:

```
var link = <a href='/controllerName/Edit/' + data.id>EDIT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With pur JS:

```
var link = document.createElement('a'); 
link.textContent = 'Edit';
link.href = "/controllerName/Edit/" + data.id;
```

you just need to place this inside your td.
If you want to remove 'http://localhost:61888' you can just use replace to change your localhost by un empty string. Or split your string and just keep the second part